# c# version of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

So Im redoing one of my old browser based javascript games and recoding it in c# i really liked the layout of my code and how smooth the workflow was so I wanna keep that same pattern when I code it in c#

So I have some nested arrays that look like this

```js
var names = {
    town: "",
    mayor: "",
},
  wood = {
    name: "wood",
    amount: 0,
    increment: 0,
    max: 100,
    storage: 0,
    storageCost: {
    wood: 50,
    stone: 50
  }
};
```

Ive been trying to find out what the c# equivalent is but with no luck im sure this is a thing they have in c#(cause why wouldnt they?)

SO yea Answer providing a link to maybe some documentation? or just letting me know what the equivalent is

Please do note I am not asking for you to code anything for me I just need to know the right syntax

EDIT: To be more precise I wanna be able to get a value as simple as `wood.storageCost.stone` and get the value `50`

Comment: it is [Dictionary<String, Object>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) or you can create custom class

Comment: @IlyaBursov dictionarys arnt gonna achieve what im trying to do thier not the same thing as a multidimensional array

Comment: arrays in javascript are hashmaps, hashmaps in c# are called dictionaries, you can achieve everything you want with them

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to create classes for "names", "wood", and "storageCost"?  That seems to be the most simple answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `dynamic` could be a solution, I would like to suggest another approach that is more close to one of C#'s main strengths: static typing.

So, to come close to your main goal, which is to access a value by simply doing `wood.storageCost.stone`, I would create the following classes:

```
public class Material
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Increment { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Storage { get; set; }
    public StorageCost StorageCost { get; set; }
}

public class StorageCost
{
    public int Stone { get; set; }
    public int Wood { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you could instantiate it like so:

```
var wood = new Material 
{
    Name = "wood",
    Amount = 0,
    Increment = 0,
    Max = 100,
    Storage = 0,
    StorageCost = new StorageCost
    {
        Stone = 50,
        Wood = 50
    }
};
```

Afterwards, you can access the value like so:

`wood.StorageCost.Stone`

Some considerations:

- The use of PascalCase is due to C#'s naming guidelines. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members). You may very well use lowercase names, if you wish.
- Although I created a class for your `StorageCost`, I suspect that you may want to add and remove storage costs. If so, you could use an `IDictionary<string, int>`, but then, to access the value, you would do something like `wood.StorageCost["stone"]`.
- The main advantage of this approach is that you'd have compile-time code checking, which might allow you to avoid bugs sooner. More information [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135160/shortcomings-of-using-dynamic-types-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` type.

E.g.:

```
dynamic names = new
{
    town = "",
    mayor = "",
};

dynamic wood = new
{
    name = "wood",
    amount = 0,
    increment = 0,
    max = 100,
    storage = 0,
    storageCost = new
    {
        wood = 50,
        stone = 50
    }
};
```

Comment: so in theory i could just call `debug.log(wood.storageCost.stone` and it will return 50?

Comment: Sort of. .NET/C# equivalent of `console.log()` is `System.Console.WriteLine()`. I'm not sure about `debug.log()` in JavaScript.

Comment: The debug.log is actually a function in the engine I use but I did give this a try theres no dynamic definition but there is a DynamicGI definition it doesnt seem to work the same as this is there any imports?

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested using the dynamic keyword, but honestly, I would follow an object oriented approach so that you don't have to repeat yourself, and you will get intellisense on all the classes you create.